# Is it necessary to destroy the temp uploaded file if requirements are not met

Tags: php

I'm uploading files using php. The file has to be below a certain size. If it's not, the script returns an error.

I've noticed that php stores the uploaded file in (my case) C:\Windows\Temp\filename.extension
Right now, if the file is above the Max size, the script only returns an error. So what happens to the file that got uploaded? Does php delete it automatically or do I have to do that? Even if the the file was the right size, the temp file still remains there I guess. Should I be deleting this file in my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of
>   the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.